# Using QDRIFT on qiskit

Tags: qiskit, hamiltonian-simulation, trotterization

I was recently trying to use Qiskit's inbuilt QDRIFT to construct a circuit for a simple Hamiltonian $H = XX + YY$. but I'm having an issue converting the result of `QDrift.convert` into a circuit. I get the constructor first by doing:

```
>>> from qiskit.opflow.evolutions.trotterizations.qdrift import QDrift
>>> sim = QDrift(1)
```

Then I construct my Hamiltonian by doing:

```
>>> from qiskit.opflow import X, Y
>>> pauli = (X ^ X) + (Y ^ Y)
```

I checked the type of `pauli`, it is `<class 'qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.pauli_sum_op.PauliSumOp'>` which should not be an issue for my qdrift. I then get my new op by doing:

```
>>> com_op = sim.convert(pauli)
```

The type of `com_op` is `<class 'qiskit.opflow.list_ops.composed_op.ComposedOp'>`. This class's documentation exists [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.opflow.list_ops.ComposedOp.html) and it has a method `to_circuit` defined for it. But when I run it I get error:

```
qiskit.extensions.exceptions.ExtensionError: 'Input matrix is not unitary.'
```

Any way I can get my circuit? I do not see why it can't construct a circuit for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to use QDrift in Qiskit is to pass it as a synthesis method to [`PauliEvolutionGate`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html)

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import PauliEvolutionGate
from qiskit.opflow import X, Y
from qiskit.synthesis import QDrift

op = (X^X) + (Y^Y)
time = 1
reps = 1

evo_gate = PauliEvolutionGate(op, time, synthesis=QDrift(reps = reps))

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.append(evo_gate, [0, 1])
```